# IPSEC VPN - Failed identity certification renewal

Tags: vpn, ipsec, certification

I've site-to-site VPN connection between an ASA and multiple Cisco routers.
The identity certificates need to be renewed from time to time at the CA site and I didn't have problem until now.
I'm unable to import the renewed certificates with 3 of my devices:

```
RouterA(config)#crypto ca import Trustpoint_A certificate 

Enter the base 64 encoded certificate.
End with a blank line or the word "quit" on a line by itself

...
<renewed certificate>
....

% Failed to parse or verify imported certificate

RouterA(config)#
Aug 23 13:09:37.994: Read 960 bytes as CA certificate: 
...
<hexa>
...
Aug 23 13:09:38.102: E /users/michaelr/unpack/tk-003.commit/src/obj-4k/../cert-c/source/certobj.c(715) : Error #722h
Aug 23 13:09:38.106: CRYPTO_PKI: can not set ca cert object (0x722)
Aug 23 13:09:38.106: CRYPTO_PKI: status = 65535: failed to get key usage from cert
Aug 23 13:09:38.106: CRYPTO_PKI: status = 65535: failed to verify or insert the cert into storage
```

All 3 devices are Cisco 1841 with the following IOS:

- c1841-advipservicesk9-mz.124-3i.bin   x2
- c1841-advipservicesk9-mz.124-19b.bin

I did 2 renewals with Cisco 1941 and 2821 without problems (also today).
A few months before I did successful certification renewals on 3 other Cisco 1841

- c1841-advipservicesk9-mz.124-13f.bin
- c1841-adventerprisek9-mz.124-15.T13.bin
- c1841-advipservicesk9-mz.124-15.T6.bin

I didn't find any abnormality in the configurations. I use quite the same setup everywhere. Do you have any idea what should I look for? Any useful debug or something to check? I don't have a clue now...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you include the certificate please? And what IOS version are the 1941 and 2821 running?

Comment: 1941 using c1900-universalk9-mz.SPA.151-4.M4.bin and 2821 using c2800nm-advsecurityk9-mz.124-15.T9.bin
I cannot include the certificate. What would you like to check ?

Comment: You can't or you won't ? Note that it is public information, your routers send their certs to each other over the public internet every day. Anyway if you won't then can we start with `openssl x509 -text -noout -in <certfile>` please.

Comment: On thing I noticed the Certification Usage seems to be wrong:
At the identity cert:
  Certificate Usage: General Purpose; 
At the CA cert: Certificate Usage: Not Set

Comment: Are you importing a new CA cert as well? Is it the same as on the working routers?

Comment: I use the same CA cert on all of the devices. When I do renewal I only modify the identity cert.

Comment: Then I guess it doesn't matter what you see in the ca cert. What differences do you see between the working and failing identity certs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hertitu: I didn't see any differences between the faulty and the working certs.

Finally we have performed an IOS upgrade ( to c1841-advsecurityk9-mz.124-15.T17.bin ) and this solved our problem.

Comment: Weird, I did consider an IOS issue but then it seemed very unlikely that 124-13f would work and 124-13i would fail... but unlikely certainly does not mean impossible, perhaps a bug was introduced after 12.4(13)f, and fixed after 12.4(13i). Thanks for posting your solution.